# Can I say "I cast the die and it came up six"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

One of the definitions for the phrase "come up" on Merriam-Webster is:

**"come up"**

: to turn out to be:
*the coin came up tails*

Can I use this phrase when speaking about **tossing a die**? Can I say for example "**I cast the die and it came up six**"? Is this applicable in some other games where a result is decided by something?

Comment: Not much difference bewteen a coin and die, except *how* you throw it. Toss/spin a coin, cast/throw a die. Aside: many English speakers use 'dice' in the plural to mean one die.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't know anyone who 'casts' a die unless they're quoting Julius Caesar. Personally, I 'roll' my dice, I dunno about you. As to the question at hand, I would say "I rolled the die [probably I'd say 'dice' in reality as you suggest] and **got a six**", but I'm leaving this as a comment as I think 'come up six' sounds basically fine

Comment: Dice are also "tossed" and "thrown". And it's true few American English speakers (besides language purists) make the distinction of one "die", two "dice".

Comment: What @user8356 said. Here's [the AmE usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=toss+a+die%2Ctoss+a+dice&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3), where singular ***toss a dice*** is virtually unknown (it's always *toss a **die***). But [here's the BrE usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=toss+a+die%2Ctoss+a+dice&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=10) showing that Brits use ***dice*** as a singular noun about as often as they use ***die***. Probably more often, in fact - many ***a die*** instances will be misclassified AmE texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. *The dice came up six*. *The last card came up an ace*.